# Ranking pandas data frame rows on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, ranking

I am new to Pandas. I am trying to understand how to do something in pandas, that I do in SQL -

I have a table like -

```
Account Company Blotter
112233  10      62
233445  12      62
233445  10      66
343454  21      66
343454  21      64
768876  25      54
```

In SQL, if a given account appears in multiple rows I would use rank() and if I want to give a preference to a certain company, I would put a case statement to force that company to be prioritized. I can also use Blotter column as an additional rank parameter.
e.g.

```
rank() over(
    partition by ACCOUNT 
    order by case 
                when COMPANY='12' then 0 
                when COMPANY='21' then 1 
                else COMPANY 
             end, 
             case 
                when BLOTTER ='66' then 0 
                else BLOTTER 
             end
)
```

expected output:

```
   Account  Company  Blotter  rank
0   112233       10       62     1
1   233445       12       62     1
2   233445       10       66     2
3   343454       21       66     1
4   343454       21       64     2
5   768876       25       54     1
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
# recompute the sort criteria for company and blotter
ser_sort_company= df['Company'].map({12: 0, 21: 1}).fillna(df['Company'])
ser_sort_blotter= df['Blotter'].map({12: 0, 21: 1}).fillna(df['Blotter'])
df['rank']= (df
     # temporarily create sort columns
     .assign(sort_company=ser_sort_company)
     .assign(sort_blotter=ser_sort_blotter)
     # temporarily sort the result
     # this replaces the ORDER BY part
     .sort_values(['sort_company', 'sort_blotter'])
     # group by Account to replace the PARTITION BY part
     .groupby('Account')
     # get the position of the record in the group (RANK part)
     .transform('cumcount') + 1
)

df
```

It evaluates to:

```
   Account  Company  Blotter  rank
0   112233       10       62     1
1   233445       12       62     1
2   233445       10       66     2
3   343454       21       66     2
4   343454       21       64     1
5   768876       25       54     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jottbe. Very cleaver solution, works perfect!!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you like, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

pandas [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method for a DataFrame might be what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
[112233, 10, 62],
[233445, 12, 62],
[233445, 10, 66],
[343454, 21, 66],
[343454, 21, 64],
[768876, 25, 54]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Account', 'Company', 'Blotter'])
df
```

```
   Account  Company Blotter
0   112233  10  62
1   233445  12  62
2   233445  10  66
3   343454  21  66
4   343454  21  64
5   768876  25  54
```

```
df_shuffled = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=0)   # shuffle the rows
df_shuffled
```

```
    Account Company Blotter
5   768876  25  54
2   233445  10  66
1   233445  12  62
3   343454  21  66
0   112233  10  62
4   343454  21  64
```

```
df_shuffled.sort_values(by=['Account', 'Company', 'Blotter'], 
                        ascending=[True, False, False])
```

```
    Account Company Blotter
0   112233  10  62
1   233445  12  62
2   233445  10  66
3   343454  21  66
4   343454  21  64
5   768876  25  54
```